Why do English Canada common law schools require undergraduate degrees, but not Québec civil law schools?
Why don't QC civil law schools require undergraduate degrees, as English Canada common law schools do? Is QC civil law easier, simpler than English Canadian common law? Are Quebec high school students smarter than English Canadian high school students? Why are QC students more primed and qualified to study law as a first degree, whereas English Canadian high school students need undergraduate studies before tackling law?

Wait until you find out that law degrees are considered university degrees in Quebec and that you don’t even need to do an undergrad to get in.

https://www.canadianlawyermag.com/resources/legal-education/law-schools-in-quebec-admissions-tuition-and-other-info/382606#:~:text=Admission%20requirements,-To%20be%20eligible&text=60%20credits%20of%20university%20studies,be%20passively%20bilingual%20in%20one

Civil law is only practiced in Québec while common law is the legal system used in the other provinces of Canada.


To be admitted to ULaval’s LLB, you must submit the following general requirements:

Eligibility for Québec residents:


Holder of a diplôme d'études collégiales (DEC)
Resume and cover letter



As to the eligibilities of UQAM’s LLB, you must:

prove mastery in the French language by passing its approved French tests
hold a college diploma (DEC) or any of its equivalent


Compare with UBC

General applicants must have the following to be eligible for selection:

obtained an undergraduate degree in an approved course of studies from a degree-granting university; or

successfully completed the first three years (minimum 90 credits) or more of an approved course of studies leading to an undergraduate degree at UBC or completed the equivalent at a degree-granting university; or

successfully completed the first two years of studies leading to an undergraduate degree at UBC or other degree-granting university, and be currently enrolled in the third year of the degree program. (An offer of admission will be conditional on successful completion of the third year by June 30 with a minimum of 90 credits at UBC, or the equivalent at a degree-granting university, and maintenance of the academic average obtained in the first two years of studies. 30 of the 90-credit requirement must be completed at the senior level).



U of T

General Applicants
To be considered for admission, applicants must have successfully completed three full-time years (or equivalent) of an approved course leading to a degree at a recognized university, no later than the end of May in the year of entry.However, prospective applicants should be aware that almost all of our students have completed a four-year degree.


@TigerGuy it's so you have a fallback in case you don't make the bar?

@Trish, that is not the purpose

What are you talking about?
The diplôme d'études collégiales (DEC) is an undergraduate degree.
